# using a substring on a C# aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, substring

I'm trying to use substring in order to get a specific part of the date on my aspx masterpage. The reason i need this has to do with the template i downloaded and the css behind it. This is the code I've got:

```
<span><%= DateTime.Today.ToString("M").Substring(3), ((int)(DateTime.Today.ToString("M").Length) - 2) %></span>
```

I need to pick apart the current month so that the first 3 characters are in the first span and the rest of it is in the second span. The reason I need to subtract 2 is because it adds the day of the month afterwards.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Why not just use a label!?

Comment: Sorry I may not have explained fully. Let me show you all of the code for it:
                            <span class="date">
                                <span class="month"><%= DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM")%><span><%= DateTime.Today.ToString("M").Substring(3), ((int)(DateTime.Today.ToString("M").Length) - 2) %></span>

                                </span>
                                <span class="day"><%= DateTime.Now.Day %></span>
                                <span class="year">, <%= DateTime.Now.Year %></span>
                            </span>

Comment: I don't want to use a label because I'm using specific css to display it differently for a responsive site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you should use the proper format string.

This will give you the month abbreviation (Jan, Feb, Mar, etc)

```
<%= DateTime.Today.ToString("MMM") %>
```

and this will give you the full month name

```
<%= DateTime.Today.ToString("MMMM") %>
```

Then you can do substrings on these instead and not worry about parsing off the day.

Something like:

```
// You can create the variable here, in the code behind, or just use a repeated
// call instead of assigning it a variable.
<% var month = DateTime.Today.ToString("MMMM"); %>

<%= DateTime.Today.ToString("MMM") %>

<%= month.Substring(3, month.Length - 3) %>
```

"MMM" should never return more than 3 characters (in en-us at least), but you could replace it with the length of the "MMM" call if you don't want to hard-code 3.

See this MSDN [Custom Date and Time Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm trying to get the end of them month with the substring. I have "Jan" in one spot and "uary" in another.

Comment: Thank you for the full month, that worked i did try and parse it anyways to see if it would work and it did not, not sure why but it still shows the day of the month.

Answer (score 0):

You would just make two seperate code blocks:

```
<span><%= DateTime.Today.ToString("MMM") %>,</span> 
<span><%= DateTime.Today.ToString("dd") </span>
```

Comment: Why is this down voted? it looks like there is someone down voting answers randomly.

Comment: @Pedro.The.Kid, the original answer was completely different than what it is now. After 5 minutes my vote is locked in. If Justin edits his answer again I'll be able to remove it.